# Simplifying Expression involving cross product and curl.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product, curl

I have the following expression that i would like to simplify further. $\mathbf{e}$ is a unit vector. I have used the BAC-CAB Rule to obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\phi \mathbf{e}) \times (\nabla \times \psi \mathbf{e}) & = \phi \mathbf{e} \times (\nabla \psi \times \mathbf{e} + \psi\nabla \times \mathbf{e}) \\
 & = (\phi \mathbf{e} \times \nabla \psi \times \mathbf{e}) + (\phi \mathbf{e} \times \psi \nabla \times \mathbf{e}) \\
& = \nabla \psi(\phi \mathbf{e}.\mathbf{e}) - \mathbf{e}(\phi \mathbf{e}. \nabla \psi) +  (\phi \psi \mathbf{e} \times \nabla \times \mathbf{e}) \\
& = \phi \nabla \psi - \mathbf{e}(\phi \mathbf{e}. \nabla \psi) +  (\phi \psi \mathbf{e} \times \nabla \times \mathbf{e})
\end{aligned}
$$

I feel $\mathbf{e} \times \nabla \times \mathbf{e}$ should be further reducible. Ideally I would like to have a scalar expression multiplied into one vector that is perhaps a composite expression of $\mathbf{e}$ and/or unit normals to $\mathbf{e}$. I am not interested in higher order tensors.

Comment: It is only a notation device. I was hoping for more

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)?
It is the perfect tool for dealing with such problems.

$$
[(\phi \, \mathbf e) \times (\nabla \times\psi \, \mathbf e)]_i = 
\varepsilon^{ijk}\phi \, \mathbf e_j  (\nabla \times\psi \, \mathbf e)_k = 
\varepsilon^{ijk}\phi \, \mathbf e_j 
\varepsilon^{kmn} \partial_m\psi\,\mathbf e_n = 
\varepsilon^{kij} \varepsilon^{kmn} \phi\,\mathbf e_j\partial_m\psi \,\mathbf e_n.
$$

Then using the property $\varepsilon^{kij} \varepsilon^{kmn} =\delta_{im}\delta_{jn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{jm} $, where $\delta_{ij}$ is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

$$
[(\phi \, \mathbf e) \times (\nabla \times\psi \, \mathbf e)]_i = (\delta_{im}\delta_{jn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{jm})\phi\,\mathbf e_j\partial_m\psi \,\mathbf e_n = 
\delta_{im}\delta_{jn} \phi\,\mathbf e_j\partial_m\psi \,\mathbf e_n
- \delta_{in}\delta_{jm} \phi\,\mathbf e_j\partial_m\psi \,\mathbf e_n
$$

Then using the delta property $\delta_{ij} x_i = x_j$

$$
[(\phi \, \mathbf e) \times (\nabla \times\psi \, \mathbf e)]_i = 
\phi \, \mathbf e_j \partial_i \psi \,\mathbf e_j - \phi \,\mathbf e_j \partial_j\psi\,\mathbf e_i
$$

Simplification can be done further by calculating derivatives and using the $\|\mathbf e\| = 1$, but I will leave it for now.
Please note that in my derivation I use Einstein notation.

I hope it helps.

Comment: \
Thanks. It helps a ton. But how do I go about calculating the derivatives and further simplifying with 
$|\mathbf e\| = 1$
I am  not well versed with Einstein Summation convention but willing to grok further.

Comment: I hope that the following hints will remove any doubts.
1. Regarding derivative use product rule $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$, i.e. $ \partial_i f g \equiv \partial_i(fg) = \partial_i f g + f \partial_i g$.
2. Regarding $\| \mathbf e\|=1$ please note that I use Einstein notation, so $ \mathbf e_i \mathbf e_i \equiv \sum_i \mathbf e_i \mathbf e_i = \mathbf e \cdot \mathbf e = 1$.